# Stokes Theorem and Fundamental Theorem of Integrals

Tags: integration, vectors, curves, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

> Let $S$ be an oriented surface with a normal unit vector $\vec{n}$
>   which is included in an equation of a vector field $\vec{F}$ where
>   $rot\vec{F}=k\vec{n}$ ($k$ is a positive constant) everywhere in $S$.
>   If $C$ is a closed simple curve located on $S$, what is this equation
>   calculating: $$ \oint\limits_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} $$

There is a couple of concepts in this question that I don't get the deep understanding of. I know that $\vec{F}$ is a vector field and that
$rot\vec{F}$ is a key concept that is used to prove if a vector field is conservative or not (if  $rot(\vec{F})=\vec{0}$ the vector field is conservative). I am not sure if $rot$ has another meaning. We have that $rot$ is proportional in a positive direction with $\vec{n}$. So, we have that the $rot$ of $\vec{F}$ is perpendicular and in a positive direction with $S$.

I have difficulties when is the time to associate this information with the equation

$$ \oint\limits_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} $$

I know that this equation is the line integral of $\vec{F}$ in the direction of $C$. This concept can be generalized to compute *Work* of a vector field $\vec{F}$ and other physics notions, but is it calculating something in particular?

Am I understanding the question correctly?

Thank you.